# Looking for a list of Mikva'ot in the U.S. or Canada that have ramps

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, handicap-disabled-impair

A while ago, someone asked me if there are any mikva'ot in the U.S. or Canada that have ramps or some other means for a woman who has trouble navigating steps to enter the mikvah? Does anyone know if there's a list of these places?

Knowing where these places are would be a factor for vacation plans as well as possibly moving to that community. As I understand, (haven't spoken to her in a while), it's possible that she may not have attended a mikvah in several years because she cannot get up and down the steps.

Comment: This page references a book which allegedly has a list http://www.mikvahusa.org/taharas_hamishpacha.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [link](http://ou.org.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/disdirectory.htm#mikvah) from the OU lists Mikvas that are accessible to handicapped people.

Comment: If you don't see a similar upvote to the other question (handicapped friendly shuls) by tomorrow afternoon (before Shabbat,) please contact me. Thanks for the great find! This is good!